# getResourceAsStream() returns null for a test in the Android JAR module

Tags: android, junit

I have created a new Android project.
I then added a new "Java Library" module "`mymod`" to the project.

Within that Java Library module I have created a unit test:

```
<projectdir>/mymod/src/main/test/java/MyUnitTest.java
```

In the unit test I'm doing:

```
        class MyUnitTest {
        ...
         InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
         assertNotNull(is);
        ...
        }
```

I have created the file `<projectdir>/mymod/src/test/resources/test.txt`

However `getResourceAsStream()` returns null.

**But exactly the same setup does work and the test does pass in the main module.**

What am I missing?

Comment: maybe you should be the ``path`` of ``test.txt`` inside ``getResourceAsStream`` ??

Comment: I've edited the question. Thing is the same works in the main module.